# How to make a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, discord.py, pymysql

I want to make a prefix change on the servers, there is a message about a successful change in the chat, but nothing changes in the database and the new prefix does not work

```
import mysql.connector
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=discord.Intents.all())

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', database='*')
cur = conn.cursor()

@client.command()
async def prefix(ctx, arg: str = None):
    if arg is None:
        emb = discord.Embed(title = "Изменение префикса", description = "Введите префикс, на какой хотите поменять?", colour = discord.Color.red())
        emb.add_field(name = "Пример использования комманды", value = f"{ctx.prefix}prefix <ваш префикс>")
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    elif len(str(arg)) > 5:
        emb = discord.Embed(title = "Изменение префикса", description = "Введите префикс не больше 5-ти символов", colour = discord.Color.red())
        emb.add_field(name = "Пример использования комманды", value = f"{ctx.prefix}prefix -")
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    else:
        cur.execute("SELECT prefix FROM pref")
        results = cur.fetchall(); 
        cur.close(); 

        emb = discord.Embed(title = "Изменение префикса", description = f"Префикс сервера был обновлён на: {arg}", colour = discord.Color.green())
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE3uP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWoE5.png)

I've already tried everything, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: SELECT can change nothing. UPDATE must be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the MySQL query. You fetch the results of the query (selecting the prefix from preferences) but then you just close the query. You have to modify it, through a command like [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_update.asp).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner, can you please write an example code?

Comment: @XakeR SO isn't a code-writing service, people aren't gonna make it for you to copy paste. Click on the link in the answer & read about UPDATE statements.